# Is $P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C)+P(A\mid C^c)P(B\mid C^c)$ true?

Tags: probability

- Let $(X_n)$ a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb Z$. I was trying to compute $\mathbb P(X_3=1\mid X_0=1)$ and I was wondering if $$\mathbb P(A\mid B)=\mathbb P(A\mid C)\mathbb P(B\mid C)+\mathbb P(A\mid C^c)\mathbb P(B\mid C^c)$$ was true or not. I never see this formula anywhere, but in an other way these looks quite correct, and thus we would get $$\mathbb P(X_3=1\mid X_0=0)$$
  $$=\mathbb P(X_3=1\mid X_2=2)\mathbb P(X_2\mid X_0=0)+\mathbb P(X_3=1\mid X_2=0)\mathbb P(X_2=0\mid X_0=0)=...$$
- Also, I was wondering what for example $\mathbb P(X_3=1)$ would represent. For example $\mathbb P(X_3=1\mid X_0=0)$ is clear, but now, in computing $\mathbb P(X_3=1)$, $X_0$ could be anything. So which event would be $\{X_3=1\}$.

Comment: If $C$ is independent of both $A$ and $B$, then your claim would be $P(A\mid B)=2P(A)P(B)$. That doesn't sound true (It's easy to come up with events where the product of their probability exceeds $\frac12$). It would also imply that $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid A)$ which is also very far from true.

Comment: Sorry but where do you see that the RHS of the identity you suggest in your first point involves $P(A\cap B)$, visibly or invisibly, in any way? Thus, how can the RHS equal $P(A\mid B)$ in general?

Comment: @Did: So how would you compute $\mathbb P(X_3=1\mid X_0=0)$ ?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thank you, so how do you compute $\mathbb P(X_3=1\mid X_0=0)$ ?

Comment: @Surb: Never heard about that...

Comment: Sorry but the question is rather how **you** would approach it... An obvious start is, using the Markov property, $$P(X_3=x\mid X_0=z)=\sum_{y,u}P(X_3=x,X_2=y,X_1=u\mid X_0=0)$$ where each term in the sum on the RHS is $$P(X_3=x\mid X_2=y)P(X_2=y\mid X_1=u)P(X_1=u\mid X_0=0)$$

Comment: @Surb No need to hypothetize a random environment to justify a non deterministic initial state.

Comment: ?? It is. And this is exactly the property I applied repeatedly in my comment.

Comment: @Did: Thank you I erased my comment. I wasn't sure that $X_0$ should be deterministic, but it's good to know that it doesn't has to be :-). Btw, in your comment 2h ago, there is just a small typo ; I guess it should be $P(X_3=x\mid X_0=\color{red}{0})$.

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

If your identity were true it were true for $C= {\rm full\ space}$. This would mean that $P(A|B)=P(A)P(B)$ for arbitrary $A$ and $B$, which is obviously wrong.